# array List duplicate and sorting method

Tags: java

This class captures order details.

```
public class OrderDetails {
private int priceEach = 0;
private int quantityOrdered = 0;
private String productCode = null;

public OrderDetails(int priceEach, int quantityOrdered, String productCode) {
    super();
    this.priceEach = priceEach;
    this.quantityOrdered = quantityOrdered;
    this.productCode = productCode;
}

public int getPriceEach() {
    return this.priceEach;
}

public int getQuantityOrdered() {
    return this.quantityOrdered;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return this.productCode;
}
```

this class captures the products

```
public class Products {
private String productName = null;
private String productCode = null;

public Products(String productName, String productCode) {
    super();
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productCode = productCode;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return this.productName;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return this.productCode;
}

}
```

I need a method which will calculate revenue generated by each product sorted by product Name.Bearing in mind that the array List in the method will have duplicates and be priced at different prices.
The output of the method should have no duplicates and sorted that each product name has a revenue that corresponds to it.

This is the method which i have attempted that doesn't give the right output. The method is in the Products class.

```
public int calaculateTotalCost(List<OrderDetails> orderDetails, List<Products> products, String productCode,
        String productName) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (OrderDetails o : orderDetails) {
        for (Products p : products)
            if ((o.getProductCode() == productCode) && p.getProductName() == productName) {
                sum += (o.getPriceEach() * o.getQuantityOrdered());
            }

    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Are the products list related to orderDetails list? I mean each ProductCode has equivalent a product in products?

Comment: thats right. so both product code do actually match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    public Map calaculateTotalCost(List<OrderDetails> orderDetails, List<Products> products) {
        Map<String, Products> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Products, Integer> revenue = new HashMap<>();

        for (Products p : products) {
            map.put(p.getProductCode(), p);
        }

        for (OrderDetails order : orderDetails) {
            if (map.containsKey(order.getProductCode())) {
                Products p = map.get(order.getProductCode());
                revenue.put(p, revenue.getOrDefault(p, 0) + (order.getPriceEach() * order.getQuantityOrdered()));
            }
        }

        return revenue.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.<Products, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .sorted(Entry
                        .<Products, Integer>comparingByKey((p1, p2) -> p1.getProductName().compareTo(p2.productName)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> v));
    }
```

Comment: yup, I don't import products, just a second I will use it

Comment: could you put some input data for verification

Comment: i mean the syntax error it gave me was on the hashset not having the right arguments ans the stream having a mistake in it.

Comment: what it says now is that comparebyvalue is not a method of rowentry.filter

Comment: Did you import this `import java.util.Map.Entry;`